# useQuery queryKey with fetchall

Tags: reactjs, caching, react-query

```js
  const {
    data: suppliers = [],
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["supplier"],
    queryFn: async () =>
      (await axios.get(`/supplier`)).data,
  });
```

Right now in my implementation of useQuery I'm setting `['supplier']` with the return result of `GET /supplier` (which returns all suppliers). Then when I'm doing a delete/update I'm invalidating `['supplier']` queryKey. 
My question is:

- How do I set the queryKey to include `supplier.id` (eg: `['supplier', supplier.id]`) when I'm hitting an endpoint that fetches all suppliers? This is so that I don't have to invalidate all suppliers when I'm doing a delete/update which then I can use to invalidate `['supplier', supplier.id]` instead of `['supplier']`

Answer (score 0):

In your mutation you can specify the `queryKey` the same way you set the key value:

```
const mutation = useMutation(updateData, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(['supplier', supplier.id]);
    },
  });
```

Comment: but how does this work? I've only really set the query data for `["supplier"]`, would invalidating `["supplier", supplier.id]` really do anything?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I set the queryKey to include supplier.id (eg: ['supplier', supplier.id]) when I'm hitting an endpoint that fetches all suppliers?

I'm not sure I understand this question, but: you don't. If you have an endpoint that fetches all suppliers, the key shouldn't contain a specific supplier id.

> This is so that I don't have to invalidate all suppliers when I'm doing a delete/update

Invalidation will re-run the QueryFunction, which will, in your case, always refetch the list of all suppliers. You can't "invalidate" a single entry in a list if your resource is the full list.

Not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly, but your options are:

- invalidate the whole list, which will re-fetch the whole list.
- update the list with `queryClient.setQueryData` and change the one entry you have updated instead of invalidating. This is covered [in the docs here](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/updates-from-mutation-responses).